# Почему не работает циклическое присваивание стилей?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать циклическое присваивание стилей для background'a, но стили по какой-то причине не присваиваются. Говорю про эту часть кода:

```
var bg = document.createElement('div');
    var bgStyle = {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0,' + options.backgroundOpacity + ')',
      width: '100%',
      heigth: '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      zIndex: '100',
    };
    for (key in bgStyle) {
      bg.style.key = bgStyle[key];
    };
```

В чем может быть проблема?

```js
function PopUp(options) {


  this.popUp = document.querySelector(options.popupSelector);
  this.targetElement = document.querySelector(options.targetElementSelector);
  this.closeButton = document.querySelector(options.closeButtonSelector);

  var self = this;


  //Function to hide PopUp
  this.hiddenPopUp = function() {
    if (options.popUpAnimation == false) {
      this.popUp.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  //Function to show PopUp
  this.showPopUp = function() {
    if (options.popUpAnimation == false) {
      this.popUp.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  //function to add background
  this.addBackground = function() {
    var bg = document.createElement('div');
    var bgStyle = {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0,' + options.backgroundOpacity + ')',
      width: '100%',
      heigth: '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      zIndex: '100',
    };
    for (key in bgStyle) {
      bg.style.key = bgStyle[key];
    };
    if (options.backgroundAnimation == false) {
      document.body.appendChild(bg);
    }
  }

  //To hide for first loading
  this.hiddenPopUp();


  //Add listeners
  this.targetElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (options.needBg == true) {
      self.addBackground();
    }
    self.showPopUp();
  });

  this.closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.hiddenPopUp();
  });



};

new PopUp({
  targetElementSelector: '#inner',
  closeButtonSelector: 'button',
  popupSelector: '.popup',
  popUpAnimation: false,
  needBg: true,
  backgroundAnimation: false,
  backgroundOpacity: '0.4',
});
```

```html
<div id="inner">asdasdasdasdasdasd</div>

<div class="popup">
  anyteasdasdasxt
  <button>close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Значит создать ключ key:

```
for (key in bgStyle) {
  bg.style.key = bgStyle[key];
};
```

Значит создать ключ из переменной:

```
for (key in bgStyle) {
  bg.style[key] = bgStyle[key];
};
```